# Activate multiple checkbox in a loop using Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a form with about 60 checkboxes of which I have to activate some checkboxes randomly based on a user profile that I acquire from a database. I have the IDs of the checkboxes to select. Is there any way to do that with Blazor?

The first element is a select where I can choose a certain user role for which I receive a list of checkbox IDs that have to be activated for that specific role

```
    <select class="form-control" @bind:event="onInput" @bind="@D5UserTitle" @onchange="PopulateAccessRights">
        <option selected disabled>Please select role...</option>
        @foreach (var title in Titles) {

        <option value="@title.PkId">@title.Jobtitle1</option>
        }
    </select>

    <input type="checkbox" id="sma" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="smb" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="smc" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="smd" /> 

    @code{

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
    D5Users = await us.GetUsersAsync();
    Titles = await us.GetJobTitlesAsync();
    ADUsers = await us.GetADUsersAsync();
    }

    private void PopulateAccessRights()
    {

// Here we acquire a list of the IDs of every checkbox to tick for that specific role. The result looks like this: sma;smd;CM_A;CESAR_A;MBKSO_A;OTB_A;VPLUS_A;MW_A;OD_A;XP_A
Every corresponding checkbox must be ticked.

List<string> ConfigurationString = Titles.Where(s => s.PkId == 25).First().ConfigurationString.Split(";").ToList();

// Here's where I'd like to activate the checkboxes                    
    }

}
```

Comment: See here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234654/net-core-blazor-how-to-get-the-checkbox-value-if-it-is-checked

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
@foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    <input type="checkbox" id="@employee.ID" @bind="@employee.Checked" />
}



@code{ 

    IList<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>() { new Employee { ID=1, Name="Nanacy", Checked=true},
                                                       new Employee { ID=2, Name="Andrew", Checked=true},
                                                       new Employee { ID=2, Name="Bill", Checked=false}};


    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Checked  { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: That works fine. But the more I think about it, the more I feel that I HAVE to fall back to Javascript here because after I tick every necessary checkbox, I have to write back every ticked checkbox to a database for user rights management purpose. And unfortunately, the administrator can change some boxes manually and I have to check at the end which boxes are really checked.

In JS I would get a reference to every checkbox on the page, check if it is selected and write the ID back to the DB. When I have an attribute for every checkbox, I don't know how to iterate over all the attributes.

Comment: You can bind your checkboxes in two way binding, so that when you need to save the modifications to the database, the current data reflect it. You don't need to resort to JavaScript...

Comment: The configuration string that i use (see first posting) is just a template for a certain user role, describing which privileges a user has (and so the corresponding checkbox IDs to tick). The tool is used for the creation of new user accounts. When the administrator decides that a certain user should have a certain role PLUS an additional privilege for a certain system, he ticks an additional box. I have to write back all the boxes ticked to a user-db for documentation.

I store the configuration as string, not as single column per checkbox in the DB. Hence, 2-way-binding is not helping me.

Comment: I still don't understand what's the issue... Two-way data-binding ensure that the data at any given time reflect the last changes made to it. When you want to store the newest updates to a data store, covert the configuration list to a string before you send it to the database.

Comment: The issue is that I have > 100 checkboxes for >100 subsystems for which I have to do a 

If (checkboxValue_Subsystem_b)
string.append("sm_a);

if (checkboxValue_Subsystem_b)
string.append("sm_b");

.... 100 times

Unless I find a way to loop over all attributes of a class (java reflection API would be able to do that, but I'm novice in C#...), I would be better off with JS because I could get a reference to every checkbox on the page with a single line and would be able to easily loop over every checkbox.I was hoping that blazor is already capable of something like that...

Answer (score 1):

Make you own checkbox control with properties Text ValidValue and its own OnChange event 
also with a public property of Checked.

```
<input type="checkbox"  @bind="@Checked" >@Text<br>
@code {

    [Parameter] public String Text { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public String ValidValue { get; set; }


    [Parameter] public Action OnChange { get; set; }


    private bool _Checked = false;
    public bool Checked
    {

        get
        {
            return _Checked;
        }
        set
        {
            _Checked = value;
            OnChange.Invoke(); //this just tells the  parent control something happened 
    so it can redraw
        }

    }


}
```

then you can to this, This creates a list of MyCheckBox Controls  then using the @ref property replaces these  with the ones added by the for loop in the HTML after this you can use these like any other list.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button @onclick="Change">Set config Values</button>
        <button @onclick="Clear">Clear Checks</button>
        @for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfControls; i++)
        {
            int x = i; // need to make a copy here  or everything thinks it is the last one when you click it 
            String Value = $"sms{i}";
            String Text = "This is for " + Value;
            <MyCheckBox @ref="Checkboxes[x]" ValidValue="@Value" Text="@Text" OnChange="Changed" />
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <h4>List of Checked Boxes</h4>
        @foreach (MyCheckBox cb in Checkboxes.Where(c => c.Checked == true))
        {
            <div>@cb.ValidValue --- @cb.Checked</div>
        }
    </div>
</div>


@code{

    private int NumberOfControls = 100;

    List<MyCheckBox> Checkboxes = new List<MyCheckBox>();

    List<string> ConfigurationString = new List<string>() { "sms5", "sms6", "sms7", "sms8", "sms10", "sms22", "sms21", "sms29" };

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // create place holders in the list that will be replaced  by the actual controls when the page renders
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfControls; i++)
        {
            Checkboxes.Add(new MyCheckBox());
        }
        base.OnInitialized();
    }


    void Change()
    {
        foreach (var c in ConfigurationString)
        {
            string localc = c;
            MyCheckBox x = Checkboxes.Where(c => c.ValidValue == localc).FirstOrDefault();
            if (x != null)
            {
                x.Checked = !x.Checked;
            }
        }
    }

    void Clear()
    {
        @foreach (MyCheckBox cb in Checkboxes)
        {
            cb.Checked = false;
        }
    }

    void Changed()
    {
        StateHasChanged(); //redraw this page
    }

}
```

This is hard to read here so I have put it in BlazorFiddle https://blazorfiddle.com/s/0gn657dn so you can play with it it also generated 100 checkboxes  so you can see that it is fast , and the left hand list only shows true values so you could  use something like this when you want to write back to the db.

I hope this helps.