# Problem generate list of checkboxes from list of data models in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

Anyone who knows how to initialize a list of checkboxes with only myPicketItemsStoredInDabase items marked as checked and all other items marked as not checked?

When I try the code example below all checkboxes is marked as checked. I have tried with different solutions but non of them ends upp with a list of checkboxes with the right items marked as checked.

```
public class CheckboxItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

public class ItemFromDatabase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Page.razor

```
@foreach (var item in itemsToEdit)
{
    <CheckBoxItemComponent Items="@itemsToEdit" Value="@item.Name" Item="@item" />
}

@code {
    private IEnumerable<ItemFromDatabase> myPickedItemsStoredInDatabase;
    private IEnumerable<ItemFromDatabase> allItems;
    private List<CheckboxItem> itemsToEdit;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        myPickedItemsStoredInDatabase = await getFromJsonAsync<ItemFromDatabase>.....
        allItems= await getFromJsonAsync<ItemFromDatabase>.....
        InitCheckboxItems();
    }

    private void InitCheckboxItems()
    {
        itemsToEdit = new List<CheckboxItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < allItems.Length; i++)
        {
            CheckboxItem item = new CheckboxItem()
            {
                Id = allItems[i].Id,
                Name = allItems[i].Name,
                Checked = false
            };

            if (myPickedItemsStoredInDatabase.Any(p => p.Id == item.Id))
            {
                item.Checked = true;
            }

            itemsToEdit.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

CheckBoxItemComponent.razor

[Activate multiple checkbox in a loop using Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930359/activate-multiple-checkbox-in-a-loop-using-blazor)

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind=isChecked />@Item.Name<br />

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public CheckboxItem Item { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<CheckboxItem> Items { get; set; }

    private bool isChecked
    {
        get => Items.Any(el => el.Name == Value);
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                if (!Items.Any(el => el.Name == Value))
                    Items.Add(Item);
            }
            else
                Items.Remove(Item);
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what should happen in isChecked.
To set checked you can modify the CheckBoxItemComponent.razor like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind=isChecked /> @Item.Name
<br />
@code
{

    [Parameter]
    public CheckboxItem Item { get; set; }

    public bool isChecked
    {
        get => this.Item.Checked;
        set => this.Item.Checked = value;
    }
}
```

And use it in Page.razor:

```
@foreach (var item in itemsToEdit)
{
    <CheckBoxItemComponent Item="@item" />
}
```

Comment: Thank you PinBack, you helped my day! Your solution solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very careful when using:

```
@foreach (var item in itemsToEdit)
{
    <CheckBoxItemComponent Items="@itemsToEdit" Value="@item.Name" Item="@item" />
}
```

This is Razor, not a C# code file.  You can find and examine the C# pre-compiled file in obj/debug/net5.0/razor/pages/page.razor.g.cs if your razor file is called page in the pages directory.

if you consume `item` during the loop - like setting a value to a primitive type, all works fine.  BUT any object references - such as `Item="@item"` - can easily end up pointing to the last item - the one after the foreach finishes.  This may be what's happening - your testing checking on the last `item`.  Try setting a local variable in the loop to `item` and then using that for the component parameters. See below.

```
@foreach (var item in itemsToEdit)
{
    var thisitem = item;
    <CheckBoxItemComponent Items="@itemsToEdit" Value="@thisitem.Name" Item="@thisitem" />
}
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman.  As I said "May".  Having coded these since early Blazor, I quickly switched to using the local loop variable as a matter of course without investigating and realising that FOR was the culprit.  You learn something new every day.

Comment: If you wish to delete the answer, just click the delete link. Editing out the content is not the way to do it.