# How can I bind my checked checkboxes with another

Tags: c#, mysql, checkbox, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am currently working on a meal planner system on a blazor server, in which you can make a list of your available ingredients which will generate a list of possible recipes (both ingredient and recipe are made by the admin via a database). In the recipe table, the ingredient table is also located in the database.
I have a checkbox where one can check off his/hers ingredients, when checked, is pasted into a list.
But how do a make the connection between the checked ingredients and the recipe, so the  available recipes will either appear or highlighted?
[An image of the current system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXP8C.png)

This is the list of ingredients you can choose:

```
 @foreach (var ing in checkedIngredients)
                 {
                    <EditForm Model="this">
                        <input type="checkbox" @bind="ing.Checked" />@ing.Ingredient.Name, @ing.Ingredient.Category
                    </EditForm>
                 }
                <button @onclick="addedChanged">Add</button>



@code

private List<Ingredients> ingredients;
private List<boolIngredients> checkedIngredients = new List<boolIngredients>();
private List<Ingredients> addedIngredients;
private Ingredients ing = new Ingredients();

private async Task InsertData()
{
    string sql = "SELECT FROM ingredients (Name) VALUES (@Name);";
    await _data.SaveData(sql, new { Name = ing.Name, Category =ing.Category }, _config.GetConnectionString("default"));
    await OnInitializedAsync();
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM ingredients";

    ingredients = await _data.LoadData<Ingredients, dynamic>(sql, new { }, _config.GetConnectionString("default"));
    foreach (var ingredent in ingredients)
    {
        checkedIngredients.Add(new boolIngredients
        {
            Checked = false,
            Ingredient = ingredent
        });
    }
}
```

This is the list of checked ingredients:

```
     @if (addedIngredients == null)
        {
            <p>Loading</p>
        } else
        {
            @foreach (var ing in addedIngredients)
            {
                <p>@ing.Name</p>
            }
        }

@code
private void addedChanged()
{
    addedIngredients = new List<Ingredients>();
    foreach (var ing in checkedIngredients)
    {
        if (ing.Checked == true)
        {
            addedIngredients.Add(ing.Ingredient);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the recipes list:

```
@foreach (var recipe in recipes)
                 {
                    <EditForm Model="this">
                        <input type="checkbox" />@recipe.Name, @recipe.URL, @recipe.Description
                    </EditForm>

                 }
@code 
 List<Recipes> recipes;
private Recipes recipe = new Recipes();
private Recipes DeleteForm = new Recipes();




 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    
    string abc = "SELECT * FROM recipes";

    recipes = await _data.LoadData<Recipes, dynamic>(abc, new { }, _config.GetConnectionString("default"));
}

private async Task InsertDataRecipe()
{
    string sql = "INSERT INTO recipes (Name, Ingredient, Description, URL, Admin_admin_id) VALUES (@Name, @Ingredient, @Description, @URL, @Admin_admin_ID);";
    await _data.SaveData(sql, new { Name = recipe.Name, Ingredient = recipe.Ingredient, Description = recipe.Description, Url = recipe.URL, Admin_admin_ID = recipe.Admin_admin_ID }, _config.GetConnectionString("default"));
    await OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

Hope you guys could help.

Comment: `@if (recipes.Contains())
                    {
                        <ul>
                        </ul>
                        @foreach (var recipe in recipes)
                        {
                            <EditForm Model="this">
                                <li>
                                    @recipe.Name <br /> <p style="font-weight: bold;">Description:</p> @recipe.Description <br /> <a href="url">@recipe.URL</a>
                                </li>
                            </EditForm>

                        }
                     }`

Comment: What can i add to the recipes.Contains() if statement to get the recipes which ingredients match?

Answer (score 0):

You can will need to bind to the `onchange` event of the checkbox to trigger the data fetching process.
In this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234654/net-core-blazor-how-to-get-the-checkbox-value-if-it-is-checked) you can look up how to do that.

Comment: I am not sure, I get what you mean. Could you elaborate?